# How can I effectively utilize the Dask `map_overlap` function when working with two input arrays of different sizes?

Tags: dask

I'm working with two variables, which can be thought of as matrices - 'a' with dimensions (100, 100) and 'b' with dimensions (200, 200). My goal is to perform a computation involving both 'a' and 'b', but first, I need to upscale 'a' by a factor of 2 to match the size of 'b'. Subsequently, I intend to apply my custom function, crucially utilizing Dask's `map_overlap` function to ensure that it operates efficiently with specified overlaps. Ultimately, I aim to obtain a result that matches the size of 'b.'
Below, I've provided Python code that demonstrates this scenario.

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import zoom

data = da.ones((40, 140,140), chunks=(10, 40,40))
data2 = da.ones((80, 280, 280), chunks=(10, 40,40))
data_upsampled = da.map_blocks(lambda x: zoom(x,2), data, dtype = np.uint16, chunks=(20,80,80))

res = da.map_overlap(lambda x,y: x+y, data_upsampled, data2, depth = (5,10,10), boundary="constant")
```

However I get this error:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 10
      7 data2 = da.ones((80, 280, 280), chunks=(10, 40,40))
      8 data_upsampled = da.map_blocks(lambda x: zoom(x,2), data, dtype = np.uint16, chunks=(20,80,80))
---> 10 res = da.map_overlap(lambda x,y: x+y, data_upsampled, data2, depth = (5,10,10), boundary="constant")
     11 #data_upsampled.to_hdf5('myfile.hdf5', '/up_sampled')

File \AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\napari\lib\site-packages\dask\array\overlap.py:693, in map_overlap(func, depth, boundary, trim, align_arrays, allow_rechunk, *args, **kwargs)
    690 if align_arrays:
    691     # Reverse unification order to allow block broadcasting
    692     inds = [list(reversed(range(x.ndim))) for x in args]
--> 693     _, args = unify_chunks(*list(concat(zip(args, inds))), warn=False)
    695 # Escape to map_blocks if depth is zero (a more efficient computation)
    696 if all([all(depth_val == 0 for depth_val in d.values()) for d in depth]):

File \AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\napari\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py:3971, in unify_chunks(*args, **kwargs)
   3968     else:
   3969         nameinds.append((a, ind))
-> 3971 chunkss = broadcast_dimensions(nameinds, blockdim_dict, consolidate=common_blockdim)
   3972 nparts = math.prod(map(len, chunkss.values()))
   3974 if warn and nparts and nparts >= max_parts * 10:

File \AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\napari\lib\site-packages\dask\blockwise.py:1467, in broadcast_dimensions(argpairs, numblocks, sentinels, consolidate)
   1464 g2 = {k: v - set(sentinels) if len(v) > 1 else v for k, v in g.items()}
...
   3883 # burned through all of the chunk tuples.
   3884 # For efficiency's sake we reverse the lists so that we can pop off the end
   3885 rchunks = [list(ntd)[::-1] for ntd in non_trivial_dims]

ValueError: ('Chunks do not add up to same value', {(40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40), (80, 80, 80, 80)})```
````

I haven't found a way to solve this issue and I would greatly appreciate your assistance with this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the same shape in `data_upsampled` and `data2`, you need to make sure that at least the shape are identical between the two arrays. This is because the chunks of the `data` array are not dividing properly the array.

In general, it's also better to have the same chunking between the two arrays.

Working code for example:

```py
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
data = da.ones((40, 140,140), chunks=(5, 20,20))
data2 = da.ones((80, 280, 280), chunks=(10, 40,40))
data_upsampled = da.map_blocks(lambda x: zoom(x,2), data, dtype = np.uint16, chunks=(10, 40,40))
res = da.map_overlap(lambda x,y: x+y, data_upsampled, data2, depth = (5,10,10), boundary="constant")
```